# JQuery Autocomplete function- Selected value doesn't get available in the spring bean class

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsf, autocomplete

I am working on replacing a large dropdown ( which makes a performance impact due t browser rendering) with a Jquery autocomplete input box. I can get the autocomplete functionality to work  however the selected value doesn't get available in the java bean class. Here is my code

```
<script>

var productionSourceListString =      document.getElementById("hiddenField").value;
var productionSourceListArray = productionSourceListString.split(',');
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#centerForm\\:production_source").autocomplete({ source :  productionSourceListArray, minLength: 3 });   
$( "#centerForm\\:production_source" ).on( "autocompletechange", function()  {$( "#centerForm\\:production_source" ).attr("value",this.value);} );

});
</script>
<h:inputText  id="production_source" style="width:80px; overflow:hidden"   value="#{recurringSplitBean.item.productionSource.description}">
</h:inputText>

<input type="hidden" id="hiddenField" value="#{productionSourceBean.productionSourceList}"/>
```

Production Source Spring Bean Class(To get the list of elements in dropdown and store them in a comma delimited string declared globally, which the Jquery accesses in the first code snippet)

```
private String productionSourceList = ""; (GLOBAL)

public void getProductionSourceListAjax(AjaxBehaviorEvent event){

    List<String> localList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<ProductionSource> iterator = this.getLovItems().iterator();

    while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
        localList.add(iterator.next().getDescription());
    }

    productionSourceList = StringUtils.collectionToCommaDelimitedString(localList);     
}
```

When I try to access the value in RecurringSplitBean class

```
if(AppSupport.isEmpty(item.getProductionSource()) || AppSupport.isEmpty(item.getProductionSource().getProductionSourceId())){           
        JsfMessage.addError("production_source","error.value.required");
        return null;
    }
```

item.getProductionSource().getDescription() is null. However rather than selecting a value from the list provided by the Jquery dropdown if I type a value in the input box the value becomes available in the recurringsplitbean class. Any thoughts ? :)

Comment: Does this question have anything to do with JSF?

Comment: @XtremeBiker yes the front-end of the application uses JSF hence the tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out by myself.I am posting this answer in hope it helps someone else out.

```
<script>

var productionSourceListString = document.getElementById("hiddenField").value;
var productionSourceListArray = productionSourceListString.split(',\"*\",');
var b = JSON.parse(productionSourceListArray);
var data={"users" :b};


var finalData =$.map(data.users, function(item) {

              return {

                   label:item.label,
                   value:item.value,
                   id: item.id
            }

           });


</script>

<h1>
    <h:outputText value="#{msg['recurring_split']}" styleClass="home_message" />
</h1>

<fieldset>

    <legend>Recurring Split</legend>

    <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="2" style="width:500px;">

        <h:outputLabel for="production_source" value="#{msg['production_source']}">
            <h:outputText value="#{msg['edit_alert']}" escape="false" />
        </h:outputLabel>    
        <h:inputText   id="production_source" style="width:80px; overflow:hidden" value="#{recurringSplitBean.item.productionSource.productionSourceCode}">

        </h:inputText>

        <h:inputText  id="production_source_description" style="width:180px ;background-color: #E5E5E5;" value="#{recurringSplitBean.item.productionSource.description}">

        </h:inputText>
```

In a nutshell, the reason the value didn't become available in the bean was because a ajax call wasn't being triggered by the autocomplete function. Since I couldn't find a direct way to trigger  from autocomplete script. I created the following hidden button with  having the list of space separated ID's of elements that I wanted to become available in the bean:-

```
<h:commandButton id="renderProductionSource" value="renderProductionSource" style="display:none">
        <f:ajax execute="production_source production_source_description production_source_id"></f:ajax>
        </h:commandButton>
```

And in the autcomplete function, I execute the hiddenButton.click() function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#centerForm\\:production_source").autocomplete({ source : finalData, minLength: 3,  select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var label = ui.item.label;
      var value=ui.item.value;
      var id = ui.item.id;
      $( "#centerForm\\:production_source" ).attr("value",label);
      $( "#centerForm\\:production_source_description" ).attr("value",value);
      $( "#centerForm\\:production_source_id" ).attr("value",id);
      $("#centerForm\\:renderProductionSource").click();
     } });   
});
```